# Installing eth-brownie with pipx issue

Tags: python, pip, brownie, ether, pipx

Hey so I'm trying to install eth-brownie with pipx using the command:

`pipx install eth-brownie`

Unfortunatly this gives me an error message which I'm having a lot of trouble understanding. I know I should be able to install it using pip but using pipx gives me the freedom of having venv with it. Is there anyway I can make this work using pipx? Below is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code        
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\roaming\python\python310\scripts\pipx.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 779, in cli
    return run_pipx_command(parsed_pipx_args)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 202, in run_pipx_command
    return commands.install(
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\commands\install.py", line 60, in install
    venv.install_package(
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\venv.py", line 238, in install_package
    subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error(pip_process)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\util.py", line 349, in subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error
    print(completed_process.stderr, file=pip_error_fh, end="")
  File "C:\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 559: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp turns out that brownie doesnt work for python 3.10.0 atm no matter what you do. I installed pyenv-win to deal with this and ended up reinstalling everything into a python 3.9.9 version which is compatible with eth-brownie and everything worked. kind of a pain to run pip-install on everything again but its worth it in the end if everything works i guess. good luck to everyone with the same issue.